# Merging streams in scala

Tags: scala, merge, stream

I need help with merging two streams into one. The output has to be as follows:

```
(elem1list1#elem1list2, elem2list1#elem2list2...)
```

and the function breaks if any of streams is empty

```
def mergeStream(a: Stream[A], b: Stream[A]):Stream[A] = 
if (a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty) Nil
else (a,b) match {
case(x#::xs, y#::ys) => x#::y
}
```

Any clue how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also `zip` two `Stream`s together, which will truncate the longer `Stream`, and `flatMap` them out of the tuples:

```
a.zip(b).flatMap { case (a, b) => Stream(a, b) }
```

Though I cannot speak to it's efficiency.

```
scala> val a = Stream(1,2,3,4)
a: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> val b = Stream.from(3)
b: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(3, ?)

scala> val c = a.zip(b).flatMap { case (a, b) => Stream(a, b) }.take(10).toList
c: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def mergeStream(s1: Stream[Int], s2: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = (s1, s2) match {
  case (x#::xs, y#::ys) => x #:: y #:: mergeStream(xs, ys)
  case _ => Stream.empty
}

scala> mergeStream(Stream.from(1), Stream.from(100)).take(10).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 100, 2, 101, 3, 102, 4, 103, 5, 104)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use interleave from scalaz:

```
scala> (Stream(1,2) interleave Stream.from(10)).take(10).force
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 10, 2, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
```